Relationship between the golden ratio, the triangle inequality and the roots of cubic equations.
There is experimental evidence to suggest an interesting relationship between the golden ratio $\phi$, the triangle inequality and the roots of cubic equations.

Let $\phi$ be the Golden Ratio. If $\phi/2 < A,B,C,D \le 1$ then the absolute values of root of the equations $Ax^3 - x^2 - Cx + D = 0$ and $Ax^3 + Bx^2 - x - D = 0$ satisfy the triangle inequality. The result is not true for any other constant $< \phi/2$.

Experimental Evidences: Here is the evidence for $Ax^3 - x^2 - Cx + D = 0$; the case for $Ax^3 + Bx^2 - x - D = 0$ follows a similar argument. Taking $A = \phi/2$ and $C = 1$ in $Ax^3 - x^2 - Cx + D = 0$, we observe that the absolute values of the roots of the equation
$$
\frac{\phi}{2}x^3 -x^2 - x + \frac{\phi}{2} = 0
$$
are $(1, \phi, \phi-1)$ and they barely manage to satisfy the triangle inequality i.e. the degenerate case in which the sum of two sides is equal to the third side. I ran a $10^9$ simulations with $\phi/2 < A,C,D \le 1$ to find a polynomial $Ax^3 - x^2 - Cx + D = 0$ whose absolute value of roots did not satisfy the triangle inequality. I could not find any. But if one or more of $A,C,D$ is $< \phi/2$ then I found several cubics whose modulus of roots did not satisfy the triangle inequality e.g.
$$
0.8010551301129247x^3 - 0.9990521482446281x^2 - x  + 0.808344029807241 = 0
$$
So it seems that $\phi/2$ is the tipping point. Can this be proved or disproved?
Update: Below is a list of all similar experimental relationa observed so far. Let $S$ be the set of cubic equations whose absolute value of roots form a triangle and let $0 \le a,b,c,d \le 1, a \ne 0$. We have:

If $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + 1 \in S$ then $\displaystyle \min(a,b,c) \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

If $ax^3 + bx^2 + x + d \in S$ then $\displaystyle \min(a,b,d) \ge \frac{1}{3}$.

If $ax^3 + x^2 + cx + d \in S$ then $\displaystyle \min(a,b,c,d) \ge \frac{2\cdot 2^{2/3}}{2 + 3\cdot 2^{1/3}}$.

If $x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \in S$ then $\displaystyle \min(b,c,d) \ge \frac{1}{4}$.

If $ax^3 - x^2 - cx + d \in S$ then $\displaystyle \min(b,c,d) \ge \frac{\phi}{2}$ where $\phi$ is the Golden Ratio and is the positive root of $t^2 - t - 1 = 0$.

If $ax^3 + bx^2 - x - d \in S$ then $\displaystyle \min(b,c,d) \ge \frac{\phi}{2}$ where $\phi$ is the Golden Ratio and is the positive root of $t^2 - t - 1 = 0$.

If $ax^3 - x^2 + cx + d \in S$ then $\displaystyle \min(b,c,d) 
\ge \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \left(\cosh\left(\frac{1}{3}\cosh^{-1}\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)^{-1} \approx 0.3774388$ is the real root of $t^3 - t - 1 = 0$.


Related question: Cubic equations whose absolute values of roots form a triangle?

Maybe the following is helpful: The nonnegative numbers $a,$ $b$ and $c$ satisfy the triangle inequality if and only if the radicand in Heron's formula is nonnegative. This radicand in turn is a symmetric expression in $a,$ $b$ and $c$ and hence can be written in terms of the coefficients of the cubic polynomial. This may give way to a strategy to tackle this problem without actually knowing the roots.

I just noticed that the sign of $a,$ $b$ and $c$ is irrelevant, because $a,$ $b$ and $c$ only appear with even powers in the radicand.
By the way $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)$ $=$ $e_1(4e_1e_2-e_1^3-8e_3)$ with $e_1=a+b+c,$ $e_2=ab+ac+bc$ and $e_3=abc.$

I've been working along similar lines to @ReinhardMeier (which basically does the real case). It's a little tricky to convert into a concise answer, though. Perhaps it'd be worth asking a more general question such as "what conditions guarantee that the absolute values of the roots of a cubic with real coefficients satisfy the triangle inequality?" without the additional conditions both of the current questions impose. The two questions you've asked so far then both follow naturally from that general one.

@ChrisLewis I have been working on the general question. This and the linked question addresses in total three different equations and I have obtained similar interesting results with well known constant. So far the results seem to depend on the term whose coefficient is $1$. I haven't observed an obvious general pattern yet but that does not mean it does not exist. I will share all my results as an answer or an update to this post shortly.

@NilotpalSinha re the more general question, one thing you might try is calculating the boundary of the subspace you're interested in in "coefficient space" (it's a surface in that space). You can treat the cases of real and complex roots separately; for all real roots, the approach discussed above works. For complex, you can parameterise the surface using the real root and the argument of the complex roots.
